# Vim9script commands from command line result in E1124. Is it normal?

Tags: vimscript, vim9, vim9script

If I run e.g. `:var a = 1` from the command line I end up in *E1124: "var" cannot be used in legacy vimscript*. Running on MacVim 9.0.1276.

Is it normal behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use the vim9 script syntax your script must include as the first command `vim9script`.

```
vim9script

var a = 1
```

On the command line to run vim9 script command you have to prefix them with `:vim9`

```
:vim9 g:a = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

This is because the commandline runs `:legacy`-mode by default unless `:vim9cmd` is used.

Comment: Is there any way to change the default behavior?

Comment: @Barzi2001 Not currently.